# ORDER BY getting executed before SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was solving one of the questions in SQL named Occupations on Hackerrank. Unable to figure myself, I looked up a solution. Most of it I was able to understand, however got stuck on one thing.

So, there was a subquery that goes like:

```
set @r1=0, @r2=0, @r3=0, @r4=0;
select case when Occupation='Doctor' then (@r1:=@r1+1)
            when Occupation='Professor' then (@r2:=@r2+1)
            when Occupation='Singer' then (@r3:=@r3+1)
            when Occupation='Actor' then (@r4:=@r4+1) end as RowNumber,
    case when Occupation='Doctor' then Name end as Doctor,
    case when Occupation='Professor' then Name end as Professor,
    case when Occupation='Singer' then Name end as Singer,
    case when Occupation='Actor' then Name end as Actor
  from OCCUPATIONS;
```

which resulted in something like:

```
1 NULL Ashley NULL NULL
1 NULL NULL NULL Samantha
1 Julia NULL NULL NULL
2 NULL Britney NULL NULL
3 NULL Maria NULL NULL
4 NULL Meera NULL NULL
2 Priya NULL NULL NULL
5 NULL Priyanka NULL NULL
2 NULL NULL NULL Jennifer
3 NULL NULL NULL Ketty
6 NULL Belvet NULL NULL
7 NULL Naomi NULL NULL
1 NULL NULL Jane NULL
2 NULL NULL Jenny NULL
3 NULL NULL Kristeen NULL
4 NULL NULL Christeen NULL
4 NULL NULL NULL Eve
3 Aamina NULL NULL NULL
```

Meanwhile if ORDER BY Name is added at the end of the query, it gives:

```
1 Aamina NULL NULL NULL
1 NULL Ashley NULL NULL
2 NULL Belvet NULL NULL
3 NULL Britney NULL NULL
1 NULL NULL Christeen NULL
1 NULL NULL NULL Eve
2 NULL NULL Jane NULL
2 NULL NULL NULL Jennifer
3 NULL NULL Jenny NULL
2 Julia NULL NULL NULL
3 NULL NULL NULL Ketty
4 NULL NULL Kristeen NULL
4 NULL Maria NULL NULL
5 NULL Meera NULL NULL
6 NULL Naomi NULL NULL
3 Priya NULL NULL NULL
7 NULL Priyanka NULL NULL
4 NULL NULL NULL Samantha
```

I was wondering how the ORDER BY is impacting the calculation of column RowNumber. It seems as if it is getting recalculated after ORDER BY statement.

Please spare me if I am missing something obvious here as I am still very new to this.

Comment: Yes, when the output expression is user-defined variable-dependent then output expressions is processing and evaluation is performed after ORDER BY. In most cases the output is ordering-dependent, and deterministic ORDER BY is compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering how the ORDER BY is impacting the calculation of
> column RowNumber. It seems as if it is getting recalculated after
> ORDER BY statement.

No.
`RowNumber` is not getting re-calculated.

From your second output; it Looks like, you are using `order by name`.

This will arrange all names returned by the earlier query in `alphabetical order`.

In other words, it sorts the `name` field in alphabetical order but do not recalculate `RowNumber` Or result of the query.

If you observe the results pasted by you, neglecting all nulls; you can find field `name` is alphabetically sorted in ascending order as follows :

```
Aamina 
Ashley
Belvet
Britney
Christeen 
Eve
Jane 
Jennifer
Jenny 
Julia 
Ketty
Kristeen 
Maria
Meera
Naomi
Priya 
Priyanka
Samantha
```

The `ORDER BY` keyword is used to sort the `result-set` in ascending or descending order.

The `ORDER BY` keyword sorts the `records` in ascending order by default.

To sort the records in descending order one needs to explicitly use the DESC keyword.

For Ex :

If you use : `order by name desc`;

The above resultset will be sorted in descending order of alphabets